# How to make another search call inside SOLR

Tags: solr

I would like to implement some kind of fallback querying mechanism inside SOLR. That is if a first search call doesn't generate enough results, I would like to make another call with different ranking and then combine the results and return it. I guess this can be done in the SOLR client side but I hope to do this inside the SOLR. By reading documentation, I guess I need to implement a search component and then add it next to "query" component? Any reference or experience in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SearchHandler calls all the registered search components in order you define, and there are several stages (prepare,process etc.).
You know the number of results only after the distributed processing phase (I suppose you work with distributed mode),so your custom search component should check the number of results in response object and run its own query if necessary.
Actually you may inherit (or wrap) a regular QueryComponent for that, augmenting its process/distributed process phases.